# github login with gh tool with ssh key only

Tags: github

## Problem description

I'm using the command:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my description" -N "" -f ~/.ssh/gh-test
gh repo deploy-key add ~/.ssh/gh-test
```

But I get this error then:

```
To get started with GitHub CLI, please run:  gh auth login
Alternatively, populate the GH_TOKEN environment variable with a GitHub API authentication token.
```

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_deploy-key_add

## My assumption

Since github.com only has personalized access tokens and I don't want to add a 'machine only user' to the repository I'm forced to use ssh keys.

But this kinda forces me to use the API-KEY again. Thought the whole idea was to NOT have to use this.

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

My original use-case was to use the `id_rsa` key to do:

```
 gh release create --notes "v1.2" "v1.2" README.md
```

But it turns out that the `gh` tool can only be used with an API_KEY. So that said, I'll create another 'virtual' github user which will be associated with that repository so I can generate a API_KEY with only the required scope of 'one' repository.

Too bad that GH does not also have 'Project Access Tokens' as gitlab does.

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys

Answer (score 1):

You need to authenticate the GitHub client to deploy your ssh key.

So yes, you need a personalized access token, but only to deploy the key. Afterwards you should be able use the ssh key to access your repository.

Comment: But I've added that key in https://github.com/orga/repo-name/settings/keys already. Why would I have to do this again?

Comment: If you already imported the key, why do you want to do it again?

Comment: My main intention is to use: `gh release create --notes "v1.2" "v1.2" README.md` and I falsely assumed that this `gh repo deploy-key ...` refered to the local repository in a way that I can use the `gh` tool.

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't. I don't think you can do that using deploy keys.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'd wish they had written in their documentation that the `gh` tool basically requires a API TOKEN. TBH, not exactly sure what that deployment key can be used for then. I clone the repository with it and I can probably do git push/pull but assumed one can do more with it. Thanks for your help!